# Refreshing page on checkbox click without submit button

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, online-store

I am creating online shopping website. And I am new to Ajax and jQuery. The question is: i have selection of colors for t-shirts:
1. Red
2. Blue
3. Green.

I want to load the colored t-shirts image from database (i have stored by image URL) based on user's selection with out submit button. that is, the page should be refreshed every time user selects/de-selects check-box. Can anybody help regarding this? Any help would be great. thank you.
The code I tried is:

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "mydb";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    // options
    $options = array(
        'Blue' => 'Blue', 
        'red' => 'red', 
        'Green' => 'Green', 
        );

    // sql where
    $sql_where = array('1');
    foreach ($options as $option)
    {
        if (isset($_POST[$option])) $sql_where[] = "field = '$option'";
    }


    // query data
    $res = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM try WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $sql_where));


    // html
    $sql_where = array('1');
    foreach ($options as $name => $option)
    {
        ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="<?= $option?>" id="<?= $option?>" value="1" />
            <label for="<?= $option?>"><?= $name?></label>
        <?php
    }
    echo mysqli_num_rows($res);

    ?>
```

the code does not refreshes itself everytime I click on checkbox.

Comment: please add complete code snippet to question and point out what's not working note: dont add code in comments

Comment: The obvious choice would be to use a jQuery event to trigger whenever the check-box is changed. Assuming you have tried this, please show us what you have so far and any information you can about where it goes wrong.

Comment: I am very new for jQuery. If you can quote some examples of same kind, it would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will get you on the right lines...

```
$("#check").click(function(){
    $(".myform").submit();
});
```

assuming you set class of the checkbox to class="check" and within the form tag you set id="myform"

The effect of this would be to submit the form just as if you had pressed a submit button, any time the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: Thank you. But now if user selects Red option, the page should reload with query like: "select * from tablename where color='red'". What should I do to get this kind of form submission?

Comment: Within the php script, parse the form input and build it into the SQL statement in the WHERE clause. Although this opens up a whole new topic of SQL Injection which is far too big a topic to explain in a comment box

Comment: Thank you. Can I perform SQL injection in the jQuery code you suggested? Like:        $("#check").click(function(){
    $(".myform?id=1&name=abc").submit();
});